# A question involving independent random variables and indicator random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables.

It is true that $1_{X > 0}$ and $1_{Y > 0}$ are independent? Why yes / not?

Thank you!

Comment: What about the definition of independence? What does it mean that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: $X, Y$ independent $\Rightarrow$ $$ P(\{X \leq x\} \cap \{Y \leq y\}) = P(X \leq x) P(Y \leq y) $$

Comment: Okay, so far that's correct. And what does it mean that two events $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Comment: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

Comment: Yey. So you want to consider $A = \{1_X \leq x\}$ and $B = \{1_Y \leq y\}$. Next question: What do you mean by $\{1_X \leq x\}$? Do you really want to consider the set $$\{1_X \leq x \} = \{\omega \in \Omega; 1_{X(\omega)}(\omega) \leq x\}$$ (in general, this is not even well-defined) or do you mean $$\{X \leq x\} = \{\omega \in \Omega; X(\omega) \leq x\}.$$

Comment: I want to show that $1_{\{X > 0\}}$ and $1_{\{Y > 0\}}$ are independent

Comment: I see. But then you actually have to show that $\{1_{X<0} \leq x\}$ and $\{1_{Y<0} \leq y\}$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if, and only if,

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B). $$

Here, we have

$$\begin{align*} A &:= \{1_{\{X>0\}} \leq x\} = \begin{cases} \emptyset, & x < 0, \\ \{X \leq 0\}, & x \in [0,1), \\ \Omega, & x \geq 1, \end{cases} \\
B &:= \{1_{\{X>0\}} \leq y\} = \begin{cases} \emptyset, & y < 0, \\ \{Y \leq 0\}, & y \in [0,1), \\ \Omega, & y \geq 1. \end{cases} \end{align*}$$

Since the events $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are always independent, the only interesting case is $x,y \in [0,1)$. Now, for $x,y \in [0,1)$, we have by the independence of the random variables

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(\{X \leq 0\} \cap \{Y \leq 0\}) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq 0) \mathbb{P}(Y \leq 0) = \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B).$$

This shows that $A$ and $B$ are independent. Finally, we conclude that $1_{\{X>0\}}$ and $1_{\{Y>0\}}$ are independent.